# Использовать Toolbar без возможности изменения текста

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Можно ли настроить CKEditor так, чтобы можно было использовать функции тулбара, т.е. изменять размер, цвет и т.д., но убрать возможность изменять сам текст, и сразу чтобы текст был выделен всегда.
Или можно было б запретить , печатать, но если поставить readonly к  то, CKEditor также отключает Toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант, отключить с помощью JS на странице с формой клавиатуру, а также отключить возможность копи-паста с помощью JS. Но нужно оставить возможность выделения текста.